# How do I create the vendor file with Composer?

Tags: composer-php

I have installed Composer and have executed the commands:

```
composer require facebook/graph-sdk
composer require unsplash/unsplash
composer install
```

The output from the last is:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

However, it does not build a vendor folder. I just have the composer.json and composer.lock files in my directory. My composer.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "unsplash/unsplash": "^2.5",
        "facebook/graph-sdk": "^5.7"
    }
}
```

Comment: The third command is redundant. The first two `require` command will have created the `vendor` directory and added your dependencies to it.

Comment: You are somehow missing it, but it is there.

Comment: I know it should be there, yivi. But it is not. That is why I am asking the question.

Comment: With the information you provide in the question is impossible to give you an answer, sorry. It should work. I try it in my machine, and it works. I test in another dev machine, and it works. So something else must be different in your setup, but it's impossible to guess what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding this to my `composer.json` file:

```
"config": {
    "vendor-dir": "vendor"
}
```

So that I had the following:

```
{
    "require": {
        "unsplash/unsplash": "^2.5",
        "facebook/graph-sdk": "^5.7"
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "vendor"
    }
}
```

Not exactly sure why I had to specify the vendor directory, but it now works.